# Tomcat cyrillic console output - bad encoding

Tags: java, windows, logging, log4j, tomcat6

Actually whole question is described in the title, and I'm not sure what else I can say, 
but here is few details, may be it would help:

I use latest log4j-1.2.17.jar version,
Config is in log4j.xml file, and it works.

Appenders configured like this:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

I tried JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS like `Dfile.encoding=UTF8` and `chcp 65001` command in window cmd. My Windows command line displays cyrillic correct, but still, tomcat console shows everything but words. :/

Only `Dfile.encoding=cp866` param saves the day, and it fixes console. 
But in this case tomcat log files is become unreadable.

Oh one more thing! Latin letters and numbers displays fine in any case.

So... I tried pretty much everything I could, if you have any advices it would be great! 
Thank you.

Comment: Console output and RollingFileAppender don't fit. I assume the file itself is correct but the console can't display the file's contents correctly. In that case you'd probably need to change the console's settings to use UTF-8. If you're not displaying the file's contents but the direct output to the console then it should be a different appender.

Comment: @Thomas I have ConsoleAppender which prints to System.out.
I replaced code in question post, please watch. 
How can I change console's settings to use UTF-8?